# Kill a BackgroundWorker in VB.net if thread hangs - using COM object

Tags: wpf, vb.net, multithreading, backgroundworker

I have an application that interacts with third party COM objects. A method of the COM object that I call will sometimes stop responding. I created a Backgroundworker thread to call the function and I am trying to monitor it from my main thread to kill it if it hangs. I have additional code (not supplied) that tracks the processing time using system.timer from the main thread and I raise an event if it exceeds my threshold (this part is fine). This is when I want to kill the thread and stop code execution. The problem is.. if I use the cancelasync method it will just pend since the code execution is stuck on the function call.

The particular function call in the code snippet that hangs is "objCOM.SendDataToServer()". It typically takes 1-3 seconds to return, but if it gets no response it will just hang indefinitely and won't return at all (no errors just hangs).. there is no timeout... and since I don't have access to the source function I cannot supply one. I tried the .dispose() method of the thread, but apparently that doesn't kill it and neither does cancelasync. I just need help figuring out how to KILL this thread so I can reset the server connection and call the function again. Any help is MUCH appreciated!

```
Public Class COMobject
    Private objCOM as new acs.manager

    Public Sub CallComFunction()
        Dim bw_com as New Backgroundworker
        AddHandler bw_com.DoWork, AddressOf bw_com_dowork
        AddHandler bw_com.RunWorkerCompleted, AddressOf bw_com_runworkercompleted
        AddHandler bw_com.ProgressChanged, AddressOf bw_com_progresschanged

        bw_com.WorkerReportsProgress = True
        bw_com.RunWorkerAsync()
    End Sub

    Private Sub bw_com_dowork(byval sender as object,byval e as doworkeventargs)
        'this is the long running function that will hang
        call objCOM.SendDataToServer()
    End sub
End Class
```

Comment: You can't kill a hung thread, Thread.Abort won't work either.  Run this code in a separate process to you can kill the process.

Answer (score 0):

I am a little hesitant to suggest this - but you may want to consider using the [Win32 API - Terminate thread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686717%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

It is a very dangerous API to use and may leave your application in a potentially dangerous/inconsistent state, but for the given scenario - this is the only way that I can think off.

If it is permissible to perform the work in a separate process - Hans Passant's suggestion is the better one. It is much much safer to terminate a process rather than a thread.